# How does safe fall distance scale with the size of an animal?

Tags: biophysics, scaling

An animal has a maximum safe fall distance, the distance it can fall without getting hurt.

If you take an animal and a similar animal twice as large, what would we expect to hold about the maximum safe fall distance of the larger animal (neglecting air resistance)?

My reasoning is that the safe fall distance would be independent of animal size. We can suppose the animal of length $L$, has legs that are $c_1 L$ long. The legs can be treated as springs obeying Hooke's law. The spring constant $k$ should be proportional to cross-sectional area of the legs, and inversely proportional to the length of the legs, which means $k = c_2 L$ for a constant $c_2$. To avoid injury, the legs need to halt the downward motion of the animal before the animal's abdomen hits the ground. The kinetic energy from a fall of distance $h$ is $mgh$, with the animal's mass $m = c_3 L^3$. So, using Hooke's law, we can say that the work done by the spring over the distance $c_1 L$ equals the initial kinetic energy:

$$\frac{1}{2} k (c_1 L)^2 = mgh$$

Substitute in the values of $k$ and $m$:

$$\frac{1}{2} c_2 c_1^2 L^3 = c_3 L^3 g h$$

Solve for h:

$$h = \frac{c_1^2 c_2}{2 c_3 g}$$

which is independent of L.

Is this reasoning correct? This would mean that the only reason small animals can survive higher falls in practice is because of air resistance slowing them down.

Comment: Regarding scaling in biological systems, you may like this one: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/97655/59521

Answer (score 0):

While air resistance can be significant for very small animals (bugs) and for animals of wildly different shapes (e.g. birds glide, fluffy squirrels slow their falls like skydivers, snakes drop like rocks), the factor that's most significant to animals with similar shapes and sizes bigger than a few centimeters long is the [square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law).

Energy from a fall scales with mass and height: for constant gravity $U = mg\Delta h$. (negative $g$, negative $\Delta h$ for a fall). The energy is shared between the ground and the falling object, but for the most part when it comes to falling animals the ground can't deform much and the falling animal can deform quite a bit, so the animal gets most of the energy.

Presence and severity of injury is roughly determined by energy for blunt force trauma, because deforming a structure (including deforming it to its breaking point) requires mechanical work.

For objects of the same shape, resilience to deformation (including deformation to the point of breaking, buckling, or tearing) and hence the minimum energy required to cause a given injury scales roughly with cross-sectional area. Since mass scales with volume and cross-sectional area scales with the 2/3 power of volume for objects of the same shape, this means the energy required to cause injury $U_i \approx B m^{2/3}$ for some proportionality constant B. In words: smaller things are more severely injured by smaller energies, as one would expect, but the relationship is not linear.

Solve for the minimum height to cause severe injury:

$B m^{2/3} \approx mg \Delta h_i$

$\Delta h_i \approx B m^{-1/3}/g$

[image]

---

Side-note: run the same argument in reverse, substituting resilience to deformation for capacity to exert muscle-powered forces, to explain why a tiger 30 times the size of a house cat can jump only 3 times as high.

Comment: It looks like you aren't accounting for the fact that a larger object can sustain more deformation without injury. A 1cm deformation would be devastating to an ant, but irrelevant to a polar bear. My spring-legs calculation does account for that.

Comment: Also the fact that tigers can jump 3x as high as housecats would be evidence *against* what you're saying. Your argument would predict that tigers wouldn't be able to jump as high as housecats. Specifically, 30^(-1/3) = 0.32, which would predict tigers would only be able to jump 32% as high as housecats.